# subtracting a user inputted value from csv file

Tags: python, csv

i am using wordpad (.txt) for my csv as I fine this much easier than an excel csv.

I am attempted to create a program that will ask the user for a number, and subtract this number from a number in my file.
I have searched through youtube and stackoverflow but examples given have not matched as I am working with wordpad.

this is what is in my wordpad file::

```
345,apples,10,10
567,orange,20,20
906,banana,5,5
```

---

After welcoming the user and asking for a number from them, I will use this number (in which I will allocate this to a variable called `num`) and take num away from the number that is 3rd in each row (the user will select which item they wish to choose), this will be my answer variable. Then I am looking to change (Append) the 3rd number in the rows of the csv with the answer.

I hope this makes sense, many thanks.

Comment: Please provide more data, read this [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and We will help you for sure.

Comment: And what have you tried, exactly?

Comment: Python doesn't care what application created the file, wordpad or Excel. A CSV file is a CSV file.

Comment: my code does not work AT ALL, shall I post it even if everything is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import csv

subtr = input("how much should be substracted from 3rd col? ")
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print(int(row[2]) - int(subtr))
```

With data.csv as:

```
345,apples,10,10
567,orange,20,20
906,banana,5,5
```

Example session:

```
$ python script.py
how much should be substracted from 3rd col? 20
-10
0
-15
```

As you're new to python a few hints what is going on here:

- you're using the csv reader which is a python helper module which reads csv files with any delimiter (it doesn't matter with which editor you're creating those)
- you need to tell python that the third column is a integer with `int(row[2])`
- columns are 0 indexed that's why you say `row[2]`

Comment: thanks however when I try to run the program, I get an error which says; **" FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.csv' "**. Even though I have saved my file to data. maybe this is due to the fact that when using wordpad, instead of .csv it is .txt??       I have tried to use csv in python before and when opening the file I have used .txt

Comment: wordpad *should* not add a `.txt` at the end. I just checked and pasted the content you put above into an empty wordpad window and saved is as `Text Document` and put `data.csv` as file name. That works well (you can check with the command line, doing a `dir` in the right directory)

Comment: you should definitively work with another editor. With which editor do you edit your python code? You should use the same. If you have no editor yet besides wordpad you could try "notepad++" which is a popular editor on windows

Comment: I think I will try working with another editor, my wordpad might be out of date... Thankyou so much for helping.